# manipulating gs spring project

Tags: java, spring, intellij-idea, gradle

I'm trying to use a spring [getting started project](http://spring.io/guides/gs/rest-service/), and I have a problem I cannot figure out: when I move the restController from the default "hello" package to another one (say com.mydomain.controllers) I get a 404 error page. Any ideas how to solve this?

**PS:** I'm using intellij + gradle

Comment: Just throwing this out there: possibly your Application class needs to be in the com.mydomain.controllers (or even just com.mydomain) package in order for the component-scan to find your controller.

Answer (score 0):

In this case, this controller is located in a package that's not scanned by Spring. In the Application class:

```
package hello;

@SpringBootApplication
public class Application {
  //...
}
```

The `@SpringApplication` annotation is a convenience annotation - see the [full explanation in the guide itself](https://spring.io/guides/gs/rest-service/#_make_the_application_executable).

If you want to scan other locations and customize more your configuration, you can change your application class to this:

```
package hello;

@Configuration
@EnableAutoConfiguration
@ComponentScan({"hello", "com.mydomain.controllers"})
public class Application {
  //...
}
```